# Es posible crear un bot auto contestador para tu perfil y no una pagina de facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

he estado investigando como poner un bot auto contestador en mi perfil de facebook, y no en una fanpage.

Pero es posible crear un bot para tu perfil de facebook?

Y si es asi en donde puedo encontrar informacion?

Answer (score 0):

Por el momento no es posible, necesitas una fan page o de negocios y establecer ahí tu bot

Answer (score 0):

Yo estuve con lo mismo. desarrolle una app en nodejs hace tiempo para que respondiera messenger automaticamente pero no la pude implementar para la pagina personal. facebook aun no coloca esa opcion.

Comment: Hola Anthony, bienvenido a stack overflow en español, te invito a que completes [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así puedas obtener tu primer medalla.